# Carpet gap causing leak

Tags: leak, carpet, caulk

My house has a large gap between the wall and the carpet in the bedroom where it looks like water is leaking through I want to repair it myself but I don’t know what to use.

Comment: Please [Edit] your question and add a pic or 2 showing us what you're dealing with.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: big trouble, you should have no water leaking in the bedroom. where does it comes from

Comment: The gap is only showing the problem.  You will need to find where the problem is.  Leaking pipes, a roof leak going down the wall, rain coming into the house, a flood outside.

Comment: The carpet gaps isn't causing a leak.  Something else is.

Comment: Is this an interior or exterior wall? If interior, what's on the other side? Pics of both sides (whether interior or exterior), [edit]ed into your question will help us help you. Is there actually a gap between the wall and the _flooring_ or is it just that the carpet has come loose and doesn't go all the way to the wall anymore?